# Pylint configuration problems

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I am trying to configure pylint to accept two letter variable names without giving the 'doesn't conform to snake_case naming style' warning.

I've set up the default `~/pylintrc` and have tried editing it as follows

- adding `variable-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1-30}$`
- adding `variable-rgx=[a-z\_][a-z0-9_]{1-30}$`  (I have no idea why the backslash is there, but I found it on a random website talking about configuring pylint and thought it worth a shot)
- both of the above with and without commenting out `variable-naming-style=snake_case`
- adding a few of the common 2 letter variables I use to `good-names`

This is happening (perhaps unsurprisingly) when I run pylint direct in my terminal or via Vim/Ale. I have closed down and restarted my terminal several times and even rebooted once to try and clear any caching that may be going on and I cannot get this to work.

Strangely, changing `max-line-length` to 120 works just fine, so I know pylint is actually reading `~/pylintrc`.  Why does this work and my efforts above have not?

Comment: There's a typo in your regex: the repetitions need to be separated by a comma, not a hyphen. Change `{1-30}` into `{1,30}` and it will work. In case you missed it, there's some example regexes in [pylint's docs](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v3.0.3/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html#cmdoption-variable-rgx)

Comment: Oh look! It works now! I have stared at that line for so long and I never saw that. Many, many thanks!

Comment: kindly take a look at my answer below. I tried to address the items of your question one by one. I hope you'll find it helpful. I'd appreciate if you'd accept my answer but that decision is, of course, yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your approaches and sub-questions one by one:

> adding `variable-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1-30}$`

There's a typo in the repetition specifier. It needs to be a comma instead of a hyphen. The line below will work as expected:

```
variable-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1,30}$
    this character changed ---^
```

**And that's already the solution.** Now let's take a look at the other approaches, too.

> adding `variable-rgx=[a-z\_][a-z0-9_]{1-30}$` (I have no idea why the backslash is there, but I found it on a random website talking about configuring pylint and thought it worth a shot)

This suffers from the typo as above. I have no idea what the backslash is supposed to do, either. It allows variables like `\foo` - which are still invalid syntax in Python - yay, I guess?

Remember kids, don't put random stuff from random websites into your config.

> both of the above with and without commenting out `variable-naming-style=snake_case`

This is inconsequential as
`variable-rgx` [overrides `variable-naming-style`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v3.0.3/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#variable-rgx).

> adding a few of the common 2 letter variables I use to `good-names`

This does work in the individual case. It overwrites the (sensible) defaults of `('i', 'j', 'k', 'ex', 'Run', '_')` as [documented](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v3.0.3/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#good-names), though.

Assuming you want to whitelist `yo` and `oi`, you'd add the following line to your `pylintrc`:

```
good-names=i,j,k,ex,Run,_,yo,oi
```

> I have closed down and restarted my terminal several times and even rebooted once to try and clear any caching that may be going on and I cannot get this to work.

As far as I know, there's no caching whatsoever involved. Changes are applied instantly. This even holds true when running `pylint` from an IDE or Vim/ALE as in your case (which is btw what I'm also using). It either works *right now* or you did something wrong.

In general, I've found it very helpful to try `pylint` options from the command line first and put them in `pylintc` only when I've confirmed they work. This is made easy by the fact that any command line parameter `--foo` becomes `foo` in `pylintrc`.